# How can i get a Foreach loop to repeat 10 times?

Tags: php, foreach

I have made the following 'foreach' which i need to make loop 10 times then stop. I cannot use a for command.

```
<?php
$x=array("Seb","Ginna","Shane","Guy","Jackie","Frances","John","Alec","Jon","Sam","Chris","Paula");
foreach ($x as $value)
{
echo $value . ",";
}
?>
```

Prvious to this i used:

```
<?php
$theNames = array('Seb', 'Ginna', 'Shane', 'Guy', 'Jackie', 'Frances', 'John', 'Alec', 'Jon', 'Sam', 'Chris', 'Paula');

$toOutput = implode(",", $theNames);

for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
print $toOutput."<br/>";
}
?>
```

The previous code works the way i want it to however i need it to work in a foreach loop

Comment: "I cannot use a for " - why on earth not?

Comment: Smells like homework to me.

Comment: are you in the middle of an interview test? ;-)

Comment: @user1839483 what is your expected output?

Comment: @Ejay my expected output is as follows: Seb,Ginna,Shane,Guy,Jackie,Frances,John,Alec,Jon,Sam,Chris,Paula, Seb,Ginna,Shane,Guy,Jackie,Frances,John,Alec,Jon,Sam,Chris,Paula, repeated onto 10 lines

Comment: @Raidenace no i am trying to self learn PHP

Comment: You could also get really oldskool, as this is a thought exercise, and do it with a `goto` now. Weird how you can now, in the newer versions of PHP, use programming tricks that hark back to BASIC on the BBC Model B ... and before :D

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`for`? I don't see a `for`.

```
foreach (range(1, 10) as $i) {
    foreach ($names as $name) {
        echo $name . ', ';
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```

---

```
$names = array("Seb", "Ginna", "Shane", "Guy", "Jackie", "Frances", "John", "Alec", "Jon", "Sam", "Chris", "Paula");
foreach (range(1, 10) as $i) {
    foreach ($names as $name) {
        echo $name . ', ';
    }
    echo '<br />' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

And now for the output:

```
Seb, Ginna, Shane, Guy, Jackie, Frances, John, Alec, Jon, Sam, Chris, Paula, <br />
Seb, Ginna, Shane, Guy, Jackie, Frances, John, Alec, Jon, Sam, Chris, Paula, <br />
Seb, Ginna, Shane, Guy, Jackie, Frances, John, Alec, Jon, Sam, Chris, Paula, <br />
Seb, Ginna, Shane, Guy, Jackie, Frances, John, Alec, Jon, Sam, Chris, Paula, <br />
Seb, Ginna, Shane, Guy, Jackie, Frances, John, Alec, Jon, Sam, Chris, Paula, <br />
Seb, Ginna, Shane, Guy, Jackie, Frances, John, Alec, Jon, Sam, Chris, Paula, <br />
Seb, Ginna, Shane, Guy, Jackie, Frances, John, Alec, Jon, Sam, Chris, Paula, <br />
Seb, Ginna, Shane, Guy, Jackie, Frances, John, Alec, Jon, Sam, Chris, Paula, <br />
Seb, Ginna, Shane, Guy, Jackie, Frances, John, Alec, Jon, Sam, Chris, Paula, <br />
Seb, Ginna, Shane, Guy, Jackie, Frances, John, Alec, Jon, Sam, Chris, Paula, <br />
```

Comment: This does not repeat my array 10 times which is what i am looking for

Comment: @user1839483 Mmm, yes it does; updating with output.

Comment: Thank you & My appologies i missed a part of the code out which is why it did not work. I can now see what i would need to input for this to work next time. This self learning PHP thing is harder then i hoped lol

Comment: @user1839483 Honestly; my answer is a bit of a kludge. I wouldn't whole-heartedly recommend you accept this answer, nor use this strategy. Also, I'm guessing the resource you're learning from intends you to use a self-managed counter, like most of the other answers here.

Answer (score 5):

For. Each. It loops through every object in the array. You can workaround that and count just like a for loop, but you should really just use a for at this point.

Comment: could you give an example

Comment: i wish it was homework lol. I am trying to self learn php

Answer (score 5):

This code should do it:

```
<?php

$i = 0;
$x = array("Seb","Ginna","Shane","Guy","Jackie","Frances","John","Alec","Jon","Sam","Joe","Chris","Paula");
foreach ($x as $value)
{
    if ($i++ > 9) break;
    echo $value . ",";
}
```

Comment: You've a syntax error.

Comment: u missed the ; off $i = 0

Comment: Oopsie, thanks for fixing :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could use PHP `range()` to create an array of 10 items then use foreach loop as follows

```
  $counter = range(1, 10);
  foreach($counter as $v)
     echo implode(',', $x) . '<br />';
```

`implode()` *joins* all array elements with given *glue*

Comment: This only works if the array has a numeric key.

Comment: Yes of course, but it's still not a solid answer. It will break on associative arrays.

Comment: @Pier-LucGendreau answer updated radically

Comment: Clever, that works well and looks good :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
//start your count at 1
$count = 1;

//start your loop
foreach ($array as $something) {

    //when your count is at 10 "continue" is to go to the end of the loop
    if ($count == 10) {
        continue;  
    }

    //this will add the next integer
    $count++;

    //end your loop
}
```

Comment: Works, but `continue` should be replaced with `break` to exit out of the loop as soon as `$count == 10`, else your loop will continue to run till the end still, although no code will be executed since `$count++` is at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a [slice of the array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

```
$theNames = array('Seb', 'Ginna', 'Shane', 'Guy', 'Jackie', 'Frances', 'John', 'Alec', 'Jon', 'Sam', 'Chris', 'Paula');

$names = array_slice($theNames, 0, 10);

print implode(",", $names) . "\n<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it prints out all element of your array:

updated:

```
$x=array("Seb","Ginna","Shane","Guy","Jackie","Frances","John","Alec","Jon","Sam‌​","Chris","Paula");
$i=0;
foreach($x as $value){
 if($i<10)
 { 
  echo $value.', ';
  $i++; 
 }
}
```

Comment: This uses a 'for' command i want to use a 'foreach'

Comment: @userR2D2 You misunderstood the question. He wants to use a `foreach()`, clearly stating **NOT** a `for()`, to achieve looping a **maximum** of ten times. I'd delete this answer before people downvote.

Comment: use it:
$x=array("Seb","Ginna","Shane","Guy","Jackie","Frances","John","Alec","Jon","Sam","Chris","Paula");
$i=0;
foreach ($x as $value) {
    if($i<10){
        echo $value.', ';
        $i++;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

```
$y=array("Seb","Ginna","Shane","Guy","Jackie","Frances","John","Alec","Jon","Sam","Chris","Paula");
for($x=0;$x<=10;$x++)
{
  foreach ($y as $value)
  {
    echo $value . ",";
  }
  echo "<br>";
}
```